# Jquery Mobile Popup not stopping before posting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have a submit button, that when clicking, I am popping up a jQuery mobile PopUp with two buttons. I need the post to wait on the user to click one or the other. However, it is hitting the post in the controller before the user clicks anything. When I use alert boxes, it waits on the user clicking 'OK', but not the pop up.

Here is the code:

```
 <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit " />

<div id="confirm" class="ui-content" data-role="popup" data-theme="none">
    <p id="question">Which year would you like to select?</p>
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <a id="previousYear" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-rel="back" onclick="previousYear()">@Model.previousYear</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a id="currentYear" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-shadow="false" data-theme="b" data-rel="back" onclick="currentYear()">@Model.currentYear</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
// prompt to select a year
                $('#confirm').popup('open');
});

function currentYear() {
alert('Current Year');
}

function previousYear() {
alert('Previous Year');
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because you're submitting the form, instead, you should submit the form on click of either popup buttons. Replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"` and attach a `click` listener to any button you want in popup, e.g. `$("#btnX").on("click", function () { $("#formId").submit(); });`.

Comment: The popup is only triggered in a certain situation, so it won't always pop up. So if 'x' situation happens the popup is shown, otherwise it will post like normal.